# 2D array grid - placing character in the middle of each cell

Tags: java, arrays, user-interface, awt

having a 2d array of characters that is supposed to represent a map

```
char test[][]={{'A','B','C'},{'D','E','F'},{'G','H','I'};
```

how would I create a 3x3 grid using the java.awt library that has each character at the center of each cell?

The code below gives me a a grid but I am still not sure how to put each character at the center of each cell.

```
int sideLength=115;
int distance=sideLength*3;
int i=0;
int j=0;

for ( int x=90; x<=distance; x+=sideLength )
{
    for( int y=30; y<=distance; y+=sideLength )
    {

       g.drawRect(x,y,sideLength, sideLength);
       g.drawString(Character.toString(test[i][j]), sideLength/2, sideLength/2);

    }  
    i++;
    j++;
}
```

This code gives me this output

[image]

Comment: `GridLayout` comes to mind

Comment: And then GridBagLayout for each cell, since when a component is added *in a default way* to a container that uses this, the layout centers the component.

Comment: You may also want to get started by having a read through [Working with Text APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, but I would refactor your loops slightly. Instead of iterating on distance, iterate on the index in the array. Use the array index to then derive the positions.

```
char[][] test = {{'A','B','C'}, {'D','E','F'}, {'G','H','I'}};

int sideLength=115;

for (int i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
    int x = 90 + sideLength * i;
    for (int j = 0; j < test[j].length; j++) {
        int y = 30 + sideLength * j;

        g.drawRect(x, y, sideLength, sideLength);
        g.drawString(
            Character.toString(test[i][j]), 
            x + sideLength / 2, 
            y + sideLength / 2);

    }  
}
```

Comment: This assignment doesn't require the knowledge of layouts needed to use MadProgrammers solution. This meets the project requirements.

Comment: @Julian I'm sorry, did you miss the second section? You also "forgot" to mention the "restrictions" :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer you're right. I did forget to mention that. I upvoted your answer since i will need to implement a gridlayout in the next project. I will be more specific in future questions :)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing but smoke and mirrors...

Okay, `JLabel`s and `Border`s

[image: Labels and borders]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.CompoundBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
  }

  public Test() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new TestPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
      setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
      setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 3));
      String test[][]={{"A","B","C"},{"D","E","F"},{"G","H","I"}};
      Border paddingBorder = new EmptyBorder(50, 50, 50, 50);
      for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
          JLabel label = new JLabel(test[row][col]);
          label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
          label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

          Border edgeBorder = new MatteBorder(
                  1, 
                  1, 
                  row == 2 ? 1 : 0, 
                  col == 2 ? 1 : 0, 
                  Color.BLACK);
          label.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(edgeBorder, paddingBorder));

          add(label);
        }
      }
    }

  }

}
```

There's lots of variations on this subject, but it represents the simplest approach

## Custom Paint Route...

If, you want to follow a custom paint route, then you're going to need to have a better understanding of how fonts actually work.

I would recommend starting with [Working with Text APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html) to gain a basic understanding.

Next, you're incrementing your `i` and `j` properties correctly.  `j` needs to be reset before you render each column and should increment for each row.

Personally, I'd do it the other way round, where you used the index for each row/column to get the value from the array and then calculate the x/y position based on the current row/column index, but that's just me.

[image: Custom rendering]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
  }

  public Test() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(new TestPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }

  public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    String test[][] = {{"A", "B", "C"}, {"D", "E", "F"}, {"G", "H", "I"}};

    public TestPane() {
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(90 + (115 * 4), 30 + (115 * 4));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      int sideLength = 115;
      int distance = sideLength * 3;
      int i = 0;

      for (int x = 90; x <= distance; x += sideLength) {
        int j = 0;
        for (int y = 30; y <= distance; y += sideLength) {

          g.drawRect(x, y, sideLength, sideLength);

          FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
          int yPos = y + ((sideLength - fm.getHeight()) / 2) + fm.getAscent();
          int xPos = x + ((sideLength - fm.stringWidth(test[i][j])) / 2);

          g.drawString(test[i][j], xPos, yPos);
          j++;
        }
        i++;
      }
    }

  }

}
```